# parse JSON response for javascript

Tags: javascript

How to parse the following JSON Array using javascript??

Comment: If that's a real username and password, you should probably remove them.

Comment: Updated code below. You don't need to parse `url` variable. It's already parsed by jQuery because of setting `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: you can use `eval()`, like this: `var obj = eval("(" + myjson + ")");`

Comment: @ijse You can, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for parsing JSON with jQuery is valid and should work:

```
var Data = $.parseJSON('{"Status":"True","Data":[{"Loginstatus":"Success","agentid":1004}]}');
```

Now you can iterate through array using `jQuery.each`:

```
$.each(Data.Data, function(index, item) {
    alert(item.agentid);
});
```

And if you want to parse data from AJAX you don't need $.parseJSON. It' already parsed:

```
alert(url.Data);
```

Comment: Try `alert(url.Data[0].agentid)` ? Maybe you should use `console.log(url)` for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) lib for JavaScript: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
Just download json2.js and include in your page, then call JSON.parse like following:

var text = '{"Status":"True","Data":[{"Loginstatus":"Success","agentid":1004}]}';

var myObject = JSON.parse(text);